# chrome addon VueJS element disappears when rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, add-on

I have a successfully running developer mode addon that works in Chrome.

I would like a button on the page running Vue (which I've used for years).  Here is my code:

```js
    let isletCtl = document.createElement('div')
    isletCtl.id = "islet-ctl"
    isletCtl.innerText = 'isletCtl: '

    let isletVue = document.createElement('div')
    isletVue.id = 'islet-vue'
    isletVue.innerText = 'isletVue: {{ response }}'
    isletCtl.appendChild(isletVue)
    document.body.appendChild(isletCtl)

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        new Vue({
            el: "#islet-vue",
            data: function(){
                return {response: 'hello vue'}
            }
        })
    }, 25000)
```

The 25s delay was just to figure out what is going on.  the button renders just fine, but when the `Vue({ ... })` piece renders, the `#islet-vue` div just disappears from the DOM!

Anyone have an answer as to why this is happening?

**EDIT**: here is a screenshot of the chrome inspector.  Interestingly a comment is added, but the actual `div#islet-vue` element just goes away.
[image]

**EDIT 2**: here is my `manifest.json`:

```json
{
    "name" : " XXX",
    "version": "0.0.3",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description" : "Simple secure plugin to convert Jira-like text in Slack..",
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "js" : ["js/vue-2.1.6.min.js","tools.js", "common.js", "app.slack.com.v2.js"],
            "css": ["app.slack.com.css"],
            "matches" : ["https://app.slack.com/client/*"]
        },
        {
            "js" : ["tools.js","common.js","develop/localhost.43000.js"],
            "css": ["develop/localhost.43000.css"],
            "matches" : ["http://localhost:43000/*"]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "browser_style": true,
        "default_title": "X Islet CORS popup",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "bookmarks",
        "storage"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "http://localhost:8080/",
        "http://localhost:43000/",
        "http://52.117.30.181/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors showing up in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console.  Also, no errors in the extension manager.  It just disappears.  There is a <!----> comment that gets injected so something happened, but I don't know what

Comment: I've never used vue, but I think you may have a problem with how you actually import vue in the chrome exstension, because the snippet you provided makes perfect sense. Are you using webpack? Probably you are using the  `runtime-only` build, which would break the UI.

Comment: I'm just adding a link to the Vue version file (locally added to my package, not the CDN) into the `js: [ .. ]` node in `manifest.json` - verified that it's really included

Comment: Could you try to add a render function on your vue instance. Something like        `new Vue({
  el: "#islet-vue",  
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('div', {}, this.message)
  },
  data: function(){
    return {response: 'hello vue'}
    }
})`

Comment: Also, can you share your manifest.json?

Comment: @ArslanAli - that worked, ie specifically `message` that I added to the data object's return.  And it replaced the element completely so I'm going to have to use `render()` vs. strings (which my lazy side hates).

Apparently the issue is that Vue doesn't have permission to work on a string on. a page from an addon, but does have that permission through the DOM I recall so `render()` probably works.  I'll have to research more and will answer my post, unless you do and then I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped! I still think it might have something to do with how you import vue. I would try to use webpack (or any other bundler), it may save quite a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that Vue doesn't have permission to work on a string on the page from an addon.
The solution would be to add a render function on your Vue instance

```
new Vue({
    el: "#islet-vue",
    render: function(createElement) {
        return createElement('div', {}, this.message)
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            response: 'hello vue'
        }
    }
})
```

It might have to do with how you import vue, so I would use webpack (or browserify), which takes away a lot of the hassle in importing external packages.